# PHP & MYSQL Dynamic Search with multiple fields fails having date range

Tags: php, mysql, search, dynamic, field

I have built a dynamic search using PHP & MySQL. Everything is working fine and the code can search for multiple values at the same time.

```
$query="";
$query .=" select * from customers where 1 ";  

if(strlen($adv_s_city)>0){  
    $query .=" and  city = '$adv_s_city'  ";
}             
if(strlen($adv_s_personalIdType)>0)
{             
    $query .=" and  pesonal_identity_type = '$adv_s_personalIdType'  ";
}
if(strlen(isset($_POST['adv_s_gender'])) > 0)
{                 
    $query .=" and  gender = '$adv_s_gender'  ";
}
```

However, when I also add below code to it and specify a date range between two dates, it is giving me the values between these two dates, but then searching for other fields will not work or it skips above codes. What could have gone wrong?!

```
if(strlen($adv_s_FromDate)>0 && strlen($adv_s_ToDate)>0)
{
    $query .=" and  (date between '$adv_s_FromDate' and '$adv_s_ToDate')  ";
}
```

Comment: put `echo  $query` at last and check your query, it will help you to debug.

Comment: That may sound crazy, but that simple echo $query gave me enough insights about what I am doing and requesting and I could manage to solve the problem. Thank you very much :)

Comment: And now see about sql injection and parametrised queries

Comment: @Stawbery, what do you mean by that? what shall I do?

Answer (score 0):

The type of query that your code is generating is working fine for me. I am using mysql version 5.7.13. Maybe the error is in the code that is generating the query. Try to print the complete query and run it in mysql to get a clear view. Maybe some variables are coming out to be empty so those conditions are not added in the query.

I used a similar query on my database shown below :

```
SELECT * FROM database.subsection where 1 and subsection_type='textbox' and subsection_position=2 and (creation_time between '2016-09-29 18:46:41' and '2016-09-30 10:56:40');
```

This query is giving me the correct results on my database. Please, check you code maybe you are missing something there.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. yes, you are right. The error was coming from a code that I have used before the conditions for the date search.

Comment: @BayarShahab You should move this question to solved then. :)